# Пример: "..." Первая часть конструкции ("Пример") является неполным или назывным предложением?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

Можно ли рассматривать первую часть подобных конструкций как предложение?

"Пример" является неполным или назывным предложением?

Можно ли считать, что в данном случае пропущено слово "таков"?

> Пример (таков): "..."

Comment: В Вашем случае "пример" является синонимом слова "образец"? Скажем, в задании спрашивается привести строчку из стихотворения, написанного четырёхстопным ямбом, а к заданию даётся образец выполнения?

Comment: @grizzly Да, именно так

Comment: Вы неудачно сформулировали вопрос, а после правки стало ещё хуже. Я не думаю, что в данном случае "пример" выполняет функцию вводного. Пока не берусь ответить сам, но другие ответы вызывают у меня сомнения.

Comment: Пример в значении "образец" по семантике сюда вряд ли подходит. Лучше откройте словарь, изучите значение этого слова, а потом уже решите, какое все же значении имеет это слово у вас. Потом и будем разбираться.

Comment: @Серж "Пример заполнения анкеты", "пример решения типовой задачи" и т.п. Зачастую пишут просто "пример".

Comment: @ grizzly, ну это понятно. Ну все же это значение сюда не подходит. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, изначальный вопрос, до правки.

Comment: @Серж Странно, но я именно так изначально понял этот вопрос. В словаре соответствует первому значению слова "пример".

Comment: Давайте помяняем предложение так. Образец "Мой дядя самых честных правил" разве подходит сюда?

Comment: Если же брать первое значение, тогда нужен более широкий контекст.

Comment: @Серж Да, конечно. Только после слова "Образец" нужно двоеточие (у автора вопроса было). В словаре синонимов слово "пример" обозначено как синоним слова "образец". Но чем не устраивает мой контекст (см. первый комментарий к вопросу)?

Comment: Думаю, в данном случае будет подлежащем, а дальше - несогласованное определение. Но это без двоеточия.

Comment: С двоеточием без конкретного примера, трудно ответить.

Comment: Спасибо участникам дискуссии. Я признаю, что вопрос задан неудачно. Задавая вопрос, я имел в виду конструкции, близкие к следующим. Вопрос: кто был первым космонавтом? Ответ: Ю.А. Гагарин. Как в таких случаях трактовать слова "вопрос" и "ответ"?

Comment: @Серж Выскажите, пожалуйста, свое мнение

Comment: @grizzly Выскажите, пожалуйста, свое мнение

Comment: @serggovoroff, такие предложения трудны в классификации. Думаю, в таких предложениях   первый элемент можно отнести к ИТ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вопрос: Кто был первым американским миллиардером? Ответ: Рокфеллер.**

Это предложение? Возможно, но это **не обычное предложение**. Обратим внимание **на прописную букву после двоеточия,** где еще встречается такое оформление?

Правильно, **в предложениях с прямой речью**, которые составляют особую тему в синтаксисе, так как состоят из двух частей (слова автора и прямая речь).

**Он задал вопрос: "Кто был первым американским миллиардером?"**

Поэтому наше предложение тоже особое и тоже состоит из двух частей. **Первая часть ― это определитель/классификатор для второй части** (можно назвать его приложением).

Но вот что не стоит делать, так это **анализировать его по обычным стандартам**: искать назывные и неполные предложения, объяснять постановку двоеточия и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это относится и к случаям, которые обсуждались ранее: "Срок годности: ...", "Тема урока: ...", "Телефон: ...", "Адрес: ...", "Хобби: ..."?

Comment: Непосредственно не относится: здесь изъяснительное, а там пояснительное значение.  Здесь прописная буква, а в анкетах обычно строчная. Однако у них есть и нечто общее: это особые конструкции, они не вписываются в общий стандарт, поэтому не надо их  туда искусственно встраивать. Это видно по обсуждениям, которые не дали положительного результата. Сама постановка вопроса в Вашей редакции мне представляется дорогой, ведущей в тупик, она как бы заранее направляла отвечающих по ложному пути. Возможно, нужно было спросить так:  какой синтаксической структурой является следующая запись?

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Случай с автором цитаты и самой цитатой (Путин: Все эти восемь лет я пахал, как раб на галерах.) подобен случаю с вопросом и ответом, только здесь в первой части указывается автор? Т.к. передается прямая речь, здесь тоже не стоит искать назывные предложения и именительные представления?

Comment: Не стоит ни в коем случае. У Розенталя есть раздел, посвященный цитированию, но такую запись он там не рассматривает.  Зато нечто похожее (только без двоеточия) есть в параграфе, посвященном оформлению пьес , например: Анна Павловна. А Виктор Михайлович где? Лиза. Уехал. (Л. Т.) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=162#pp162  И все это называется правилами оформления текста.

Comment: Спасибо. Поясните, пожалуйста, различия между изъяснительным и пояснительным значением в данном случае.

Comment: Изъяснительное  значение - раскрытие содержания речи (здесь прослеживается связь с оформлением прямой речи). Пояснительное значение - раскрытие содержания слов, например,  указание адреса в анкете после слова "адрес".

Comment: Спасибо. Есть ли источник, где используются такие термины (определитель/классификатор)?

Answer (score 0):

**Мой дядя самых честных правил...**

**Это двусоставное предложение.** Сравнить: Мой дядя был самых честных правил.

Составное именное сказуемое, связка в настоящем времени отсутствует, именная часть выражена словосочетанием.

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос был о самом слове "Пример" перед двоеточием.

Answer (score 0):

Назывные предложения — это односоставные предложения, содержащие один главный **член, — подлежащее.** В этих предложениях сообщается ***о каком-либо предмете, явлении действительности, о которых утверждается, что они есть в настоящем времени или вне его***.

**Например: Ночь. Вот их окопы (К. Симонов).**

В вашем примере нет назывных предложений. Слово "пример" относится к вводному слову здесь. 
Пример.
2. Действие, к-рому подражают, а также действие как выдающийся образец чего-н. Следовать чьему-н. примеру. Брать п. с кого-н. Показать п. чего-н. П. мужества. Для примера (1) то же, что например.
**(Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992)**

**К примеру; к примеру сказать, в зн. вводн. словосоч. =Например.**

> Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Comment: Я уточнил постановку вопроса у автора в комментариях к вопросу. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, всё ли в Вашем ответе остаётся в силе.

Comment: @grizzly, если слово "пример" имеет значение "образец",  тогда, конечно, мой ответ стоит изменить.

Comment: Я догадывался :) Измените (или дополните), пожалуйста — ведь хороший вопрос. Я сам не могу привести достойных аргументов, чтобы разграничить этот случай от вводного.

Comment: @grizzly, все же нужен контекст. Пусть автор точно решит, в каком значении использует это слово, потом будем разбираться.